# Can I kill both Mick Zaford and Jimbo Hodunk in same playthrough?

Tags: borderlands-2

Is there anyway to farm both Jimbo (for unique SMG) and Mick (for Maggie) in same play-through?

The Clan you can kill will be based on decision made by you on railway station(Clan wars mission). After that you can farm the clan leader of the clan(which you killed in the last part of the quest).

My question is can I farm both bosses Mick and Jimbo in same play-through ?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, pretty sure you'd need to use a friend who has the other boss available. At least without modding your save file, and I'm not sure how possible that is yet.

Answer (score 4):

No, Just like many other quests in the game, there are two possible rewards and you have to pick which one to go with while locking out the other one for that playthrough.

The only difference is this quest doesn't say return x to person a for one reward or person b for a different reward. You just have to make a choice and that's the choice you're stuck with for that playthrough.

Answer (score 0):

No. Even if you manage to damage both sides at the same time using Singularity grenades, the game will pick a side for you. You might actually glitch the game and not be able to finish the mission (just get out and enter in the Dust again to fix).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can farm both, the game doesn't save immediately after killing one of them, so if you got the weapon you want, be sure to have a friend or another user with your other controller if you have a console, join before picking a side. Then after farming the weapon pick it with the guest and quit save also with guest alone, but you quit without saving, then you can enter the game and farm the other side while your other user still has the weapon so you can let him drop it back for you, now you have 2 weapons cause you farmed both sides. And also you can repeat this as much as you like.